# How to set dynamic base path for BucketingSink function Flink?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am taking some json records from a file. I want to parse the json and then based on a field in json, update the bucketing function base path.

for eg: Json record has a field name 'user-id' in it and based on that I want to update my base path as BucketingSink("/data/app/users/"+*user-id-field-value*+"/")

How do I do it?

Code:
 DataStream input = env.readTextFile("/home/user/Desktop/jsonFile");

```
    DataStream<String> parsedJson = input.map((inputMsg)->{

        String json="";
        try{

            json=jsonParser.parse(inputMsg).getAsString();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;

    });

   parsedJson.addSink(new BucketingSink<>(""));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [BucketingSink.setBucketer()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.html#setBucketer-org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.Bucketer-) method to set a class you create which implements the [Bucketer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/Bucketer.html) interface, and uses the `user-id` field value as the sub-bucket path.